# Change video format of iPad 2 video from 720p to lower resolution on device

Tags: video, video-processing, ipad-2

How do I change video format of iPad 2 videos from 720p to a lower resolution on the iPad 2 device?  I'm storing it to the localhost (not the photo album) before sending it to a server.